# How to setup mail account on "Mail" application of Mac OS for following criteria

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, imap, apple-mail

I am used to access my company's mail account via a web-browser as follows.

[image]

If I am on windows, I can easily configure my mail account with Microsoft Outlook.

say for example, my mail account is sagar.kothari@samurai.co.in ( :) ), my questions are as follows.

- How may I came to know that - my email id is type of IMAP or POP or something else ?
- How may I came to know about my email id's mail server?
- I already know to configure mail account in *Mail* application, But I failed to configure above mentioned email ID. asking for help for this.

Comment: May I suggest asking your IT person? He knows your mail server name and adress and how to configure your mail client. Send him an email :)

Comment: Try looking at your full mail headers

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy - According to IT person, **MAIL Application** need to have support for Microsoft Exchange 2007 or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your IT guy already told you what kind of email account you are using: [Microsoft Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124558(EXCHG.80).aspx). The URL in the screenshot you provide shows you are using an Exchange server hosted by Microsoft itself, as part of its [Business Productivity Online Suite](http://www.microsoft.com/online/business-productivity.aspx) (now superseded by Office 365), assigned to the EMEA (Europe, Middle East, Africa) region – see this [list of URLS for Microsoft Online Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc745934.aspx).

Normally, now, OS X has had support for Exchange 2007 servers in Mail.app, iCal and Addressbook since version 10.6. [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2500) states:

> The Mail Setup Assistant can automatically configure accounts that use the most popular email services, including Gmail, Yahoo!, AOL, Windows Live Mail, and *Exchange 2007 servers that support AutoDiscovery*. For these popular services, just enter your Full Name, Email Address, and Password and you're done. *[my emphasis]*

More details about requirements and configuration of Exchange accounts in Mail.app can be found in this [Apple Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3748). You should try the procedure detailed there first.

However, I am not sure this will work for services hosted by Microsoft Online Services. If it doesn’t, try installing the [Microsoft Online Services Sign In application for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7925). Some help on usage and configuration can be found in [this Microsoft TechNet document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee662255.aspx) – I’m out of my depth as to that, not having a hosted account to test against.

Comment: Note that while I have tried to help with OP’s problem by providing an answer, I somewhat doubt either my answer or the original question are of sufficient general interest to warrant a place on Super User. Flagged as [too localized](http://superuser.com/faq#close).